# Accurate Time Math For VB Including Division

Tags: vb.net, function, math, time, timespan

The Problem I am having is with doing time mathematics in VB.

I am currently volunteering at a school and Helping with their Before/Aftercare system

So the goal for before care would be to take a time stamp and compare it to the time school starts that day and find how many half hours are in that given time difference rounding up to the nearest half hour.

For Example. A child Gets to  Morning Care at 7:36 School starts at 9:30.

What I want my program to do is

9:30-7:36 = 1 hour 54 minutes

1 hour 54 minutes / 30 minutes = 3.XXX

round that up to 4 multiply by price per hour and my cost is 12

The code I have seems to be off by 15 minutes. I will display the code I use below. Please help by letting me know if there are logic issues or if the method chosen for time math is Poor

```
'Creating all my variables including half constant half variable times to        
compare against 

Dim DateIn As DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
Dim Month As Integer = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Month(DateIn)
Dim Year As Integer = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Year(DateIn)
Dim Day As Integer = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Day(DateIn)
Dim DateMorning As New Date(Year, Month, Day, 7, 30, 0)
Dim DateSchoolStart As New Date(Year, Month, Day, 9, 30, 0)
Dim halfHour As System.TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)
Dim ticksHalfHour As Long = halfHour.Ticks
Dim count As Integer
Dim cost As Integer

'Portion of a function that calculates cost if the time is in the right zone
If (DateIn >= DateMorning And DateIn < DateSchoolStart) Then
        CareTime = DateSchoolStart.Subtract(DateIn)
        Dim CareTicks As Long = CareTime.Ticks
        count = ReturnCount(CareTicks, ticksHalfHour)
        cost = count * price
        WriteReport(cost, Year, Month, Day, name)
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to morning care " & name & "!")
        Return cost
    End If

 ' function that divides the two longs and does a mod calculation 
 Function ReturnCount(ByVal tick1 As Long, tick2 As Long) As Integer
    If (tick1 Mod tick2 = 0) Then
        count = tick1 / tick2
        Return count
    Else
        count = 1 + (tick1 / tick2)
        Return count
    End If
End Function
```

I believe this is the relevant portion of the code. If you see a flaw in my logic or have a simpler way of achieving my goal your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear (to me).  Perhaps an [edit] with an example of what you mean would help?

Comment: I edited it to show my goal. My problem is that the count is coming up with an undesirable integer. I.e at 7:31 Cost = 15 and at 9:15 cost = 0 when desired outcome would be $12 and $3  Where Cost = Count * 3

Comment: There is a TimeSpan type which might simplify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wow, that's all?  All that code for a single line calc? `Math.Ceiling((DateTime.Parse("01/01/1901 11:22:00 am") - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1901 8:40:00 am")).TotalMinutes / 30)`

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a better way than converting DateTime to TimeSpan to Ticks to finally do math. Just shaved about 14 lines of code :)